# CSS - Div will not count a child div

Tags: html, css

I currently have part of my HTML that looks a bit like this. This is a simplified version.

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="screenshot">
      <img src="res/screenshot.png" />
   </div>
   <div id="introduction">
      <p>This is just some text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS looks like this.

```css
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}

#screenshot img {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#introduction {
    position: relative;
    top: -100%;
    left: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And my problem is is that the 'background: blue;' only selects the images, but does not wrap around the text. BTW, I know how I could put the text background blue, but I need to do it through `#content`. If it can help, `#content`'s parent is this in CSS.
Basically, what I need is that if I do something to `#content` that it affects both of the children divs. It only affects the `#screenshots` at the moment. :/

```css
#content-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 340px;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -170px;
}
```

Thanks, zeokila

Edit: What I need is that if I do something to `#content` that it affects both of the children divs. It only affects the `#screenshots` at the moment. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying a width for `#content`.

When an element is positioned absolutely, its width no longer defaults to 100%.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. Sorry I didn't explain too very, I wasn't sure how, but it solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be...

```css
background-color:blue;
```

Also you could always inherit the background's color;

If it's showing for the images as you say, then maybe add a width|height also to the div.

or you could try

```css
#content > #introduction > P {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but it's more neat to use background-color: